# Gorillapod tripod for microphones

Tags: microphone-stand

Hi all

Any of you having any experience with the Gorillapod tripods, used as a mount for a Rycote or similar microphone handle?
I have an upcoming session where an usual mic stand wont be able to stand securely.
Some of the Gorilla pods can hold as much as 5 kilos.

Best wishes

Mikkel

Answer (score 1):

They're a lighting accessory, but im a massive fan of manfrotto super clamps. About £25, super strong, buy the right screw adaptors, and then you can mount on anything. And when you own a few, you'll find ways to keep using them. Great investment.

Comment: I use the manfrotto clamps as well, and they work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I've used my Gorillapod (The one for SLR's) and a Rycote S-series/ Shotgun combo no problem.

Comment: Thanks Gary. I like the fact that you can mount the thing to a tree etc. I guess the Manfrotto clamps wouldnt do this easily right?